# Shewing that a function attains every value.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire non-constant function, such that $f(1-z) = 1 - f(z)$.

Shew that $f({\bf C}) = {\bf C}$

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you know a theorem about the range of entire non-constant functions?

Comment: You are close.  There is still a hole in your proof.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [Showing that the image of a function is $\Bbb{C}$ if it satisfies a nice functional equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/188139/254075)